Postgres IN clause accepts column name not in table
Is this a bug? Postgres "IN" clause is accepting a column name that is not in the subquery table
(note that "product_name" is not a valid column in inner_table, but is for the "outer" table.
select product_name 
from scratch.outer_table 
where product_name in (
           select product_name 
           from scratch.inner_table
      );

 product_name 
--------------
 dog door
 gerbil wheel
(2 rows)

but if I try it directly, it correctly notices the incorrect column name:
select product_name from scratch.inner_table;


ERROR:  column "product_name" does not exist

\d scratch.inner_table;
Table "scratch.inner_table" :
     Column     |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 product_code   | text    |           |          | 
 product_number | integer |           |          | 

caryoil=# \d scratch.outer_table;
Table "scratch.outer_table" :
    Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 product_name | text    |           |          | 
 product_id   | integer |           

I fixed my actual code to use the correct column name, but I'm still curious why Postgres is allowing the invalid column name to go through.
If I try it with a CTE, it (correctly) throws an error.
I also notice that this only works if I use a valid column name from the "outer" table. Is this some result of the fact that the "IN" clause is just syntactic sugar for a series of "or" clauses?
checked to see if any column name works, and it doesn't -- has to be a column name from the outer table:
select product_name from scratch.outer_table where product_name in (select foo from scratch.inner_table);
ERROR:  column "foo" does not exist

To avoid such confusion, make it a habit to always qualify a column reference with the table name if the query uses more than a single table.

Your query is equivalent to
select o.product_name 
from scratch.outer_table o 
where o.product_name in (
           select o.product_name 
           from scratch.inner_table i
      );

Do you see where the problem is? That's how postgres sees that query. Basically this where condition is always true as long as the inner_table has at least one row (regardless of what is stored in that row). It's not a bug, it's by design, to allow fine grained matching.
You can read more about it here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WHERE
In particular this piece:

After the processing of the FROM clause is done, each row of the derived table is checked against the search condition.
...
This shows how the column naming scope of an outer query extends into its inner queries.

